# Unable to load DLL System.Data.SQLite.dll after it is merged into one assembly

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, dll

To easily distribute the software to clients, I have to use Ilmerge to combine everything into single exe file, including some dll files e.g. System.Data.SQLite.

When I tried to run the merged exe file, quickly I ran into one issue, it shows the error message **"Unable to load DLL System.Data.SQLite.dll. The specified module could not be found."** This could be solved by putting this dll file same directory with exe file.


However, this is not an ideal way for me. I had tried to browse my exe file and I am pretty sure that System.Data.SQLite already embed inside. The result I get from google is because System.Data.SQLite is not managed code and cannot be mixed

I have tested csharp-sqlite, but that's look like totally different library for me. Is there any quick way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I used Inno Setup before and I added System.Data.SQLite.dll as well. Give it try using Inno Setup and see if you will run into the same problem.